# php - Filename of file when using firefox to download

Tags: php, download

I see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) tutorial to make download file but I have a problem

Here is my example

```
$file_url = "D:/my file name.doc"

header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=UTF-8;');  
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file_url)."");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_url);
```

Everything's well in ie or chrome. But when I using `firefox` to download file. The file download has `my` is the file name? How to fix that thanks

Comment: Probably because of the spaces. I don't think you can change the way a browser interprets a filename (not entirely true as FF is open-source). Use `str_replace` on `basename` to change the spaces to e.g. underscores.

Comment: you didn't close the quote in the content-disposition header. try this: header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file_url)."'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .basename($file_url).'"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should quote filename.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url) . '"');
```

EDIT: It was as selected answer just with typo in it. Now I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are missing `;` on the end of the first line.
I think the problem is in filename with spaces.
Try to use `readfile(urlencode($file_url));` instead of `readfile($file_url);`