# Mozilla Firefox File Type Issue

Tags: vb.net, firefox

I created an application in vb.net for uploading and downloading a file. On IE and Chrome, it is successfully open with correct extension on clicking at link. But on Mozilla firefox, It is always open in HTML format.

[image]

Do I need to change something in the Mozilla Firefox or in my code? It is doing right in Chrome and IE. File can be of any type(.docx,.pdf,.txt).Prompt response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the “Open with” dropdown should default to “Excel” instead of “Firefox”?

Comment: The file may be missing the content-type

Comment: You should post the code you're using to do this - it's probably a content-type issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Content-Disposition header to the response. Your server side code should look something like:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/CSV"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="" + filename + ".csv"")
...
```

Here is a similar question:

- [php - Filename of file when using firefox to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122965/php-filename-of-file-when-using-firefox-to-download)
- [Response Content type as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv)

Answer (score -1):

Try remove white spaces from file name.

Comment: White spaces shouldn't matter in file names, the above answer was posted as an accepted answer on Jan 9th as the correct response.